# Exe работает медленнее, чем запущенный в visual Studio проект

Tags: файлы, exe, visual-studio

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть дело: есть проект в Visual Studio там выполняются некоторые действия с текстовым файлом. когда я запускаю проект из VS - все ок. когда запускаю exe(взятый из папочки Debug) то он работает оооооочень медленно. с файлами малого размера справляется, но чем больше строк в текстовом файле тем больше думает. когда 1000 строк - уже все, завершения программы практически не дождаться.

```
        int poisk(char naz[],int ww, int tt)    
        {
        h=0;
        int bad_int,c,k,y;
        int found;
        int sss[40];
        int j=0;int ok=0;
        int i=0;int str;
        y=0;
        ff=fopen(naz,"r+");
        max=0;
        slova[ww][4]='\0';
        while ((c=fgetc(ff))!= EOF)
        {
            if (c=='-' || (c>=48 && c<=57) || (c>=65 && c<=90) || (c>=97 && c<=122)) {ok=1;}
            if (c!='-' && c!='\n' &&((c<48 || (c>57 && c<65) || (c>90 && c<97) || c>122)))
            {if (ok==1){line[y][j]='\0'; y++;ok=0;} j=0;}
            if ((c=='\n') || (c==EOF))
            {ok=0;
                y=0;
                found=strindex(line,slova[ww]);
                if (found>0) 
                {   ekatsim[h]=0;
                k=1;
                while (line[found+3+tt][k]!='\0')
                {
                        switch (line[found+3+tt][k]){
                            case 'A': str=10;break;
                            case 'B': str=11;break;
                            case 'C': str=12;break;
                            case 'D': str=13;break;
                            case 'E': str=14;break;
                            case 'F': str=15;break;
                        default: str=(line[found+3+tt][k]-'0');break;}
                        ekatsim[h] = ekatsim[h]*16+ str;k++;

        }
        if (ekatsim[h]>max) {max=ekatsim[h];}
        melborp[h] = 0;
        for (k=1;line[found-1][k]!='\0';k++)
        {
            melborp[h]=melborp[h]*10+(line[found-1][k]-'0');//запоминаем посимвольно время))
        }
        h++;
    }
    i++; j=0;
}
else
{
line[y][j++] = (char)c;
}
        }
        fclose(ff);
        return melborp[0];
        }

        int strindex (char s[40][100], char t[])
        {
        int i,j,k,v45;
        int y=0;int ok=0;
        v45=-1;
        i=0;k=0;
        for (i = 0; s[y][i]!= '\n'; i++) 
        {
            if ((s[y][i]>=48 && s[y][i]<=57) || (s[y][i]>=65 && s[y][i]<=90) || (s[y][i]>=97 && s[y][i]<=122)) {ok=1;}
            if ((s[y][i]<48 || (s[y][i]>57 && s[y][i]<65) || (s[y][i]>90 && s[y][i]<97) || s[y][i]>122)&& ok==1)
            {
                y++;i=0;ok=0;
            }
            if (s[y][i]==t[0]) 
            {
                while (s[y][i]==t[k]) {k++;i++;if (t[k]=='\0')                                  {return y;}}
            }
        }
        return v45;
        }
```

Comment: Телепаты в отпуске, публикуйте код.

Comment: а код имеет значение, если из VS все быстро работает?

Comment: А релизная версия тоже долго работает?

Comment: @Tataana: без кода точно смысла нет.

Answer (score 1):

у меня два варианта

- с под студии Вы запускаете релизный вариант
- когда приложение запускается с под студии, то оно использует ее менеджер памяти, который выделяет память большими кусками (это гипотеза) и из-за этого хорошо работает код. А обычный запуск происходит с другим менеджером памяти, который плохо подходит под специфику задачи.

Но сложно о чем то говорить, если даже не понятно, на каком языке все это пишется.

Comment: пишется на Си++, по сути там формируются 2 массива, по которым потом в Win Forms строится график.

Comment: ок, одно выяснили, не на с++ оно пишется, а на c++/cli.

Код, код  нужен!

Comment: ой чувствую сейчас получу кучу замечаний...
не ругайте сильно))